# VBA validation code not working on 2016 but on Mac 2011

Tags: excel, office365

Following code is working well on Excel Mac 2011.
But on Mac and Windows Excel Version 2016 the validation does not work at all without throwing an error.

```
`Set Validation Range for Project Number in Rapport
lastrow = WB_ma_copy.Sheets("Projekte").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
WB_ma_copy.Sheets("Rapport").Range("A5:A18").Select
With Selection.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:="=Projekte!$A$2:$A$" & lastrow
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = ""
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = ""
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
WB_ma_copy.Sheets("Rapport").Protect
Workbooks(WB_ma).Save'
```

Comment: Please, add more detailed description about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue

With Excel 2016 (Mac & Windows) the file has to be saved as .xslx.
If the file is saved as .xls then the validation code is lost.

Comment: If Excel 2016 saves a file as .xls then the validation code is not saved and get lost